# ajax loader login issue

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I would like to show a loader.gif to my user. If the user inputs valid username and password, would display an image progress bar for let's say 5 seconds and then redirect to the main page, otherwise, would display a loader.gif for 5 seconds and then display username or password incorrect.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
      <script language="javascript">  
    $(document).ready(function(){  
    $("#loginForm").submit(function(){  

    $("#report").removeClass().addClass('loader').html('<img src="images/ajax-loader.gif">').fadeIn(1000);  
            $.post("checklogin.php",{ username:$('#username').val(),password:$('#password').val()},function(data){  
                if(data=='yes'){  
                    $("#report").fadeTo(200,1,function(){       
                        $(this).html('<img src="images/loader-bar.gif">').addClass('log').fadeTo(900,1,function(){          
                                document.location='main.php';  
                        });       
                    });  
                }
                else {  
                    $("#report").fadeTo(200,1,function(){        
                        $(this).html('<img src="images/icon_error.gif"> Username or password error.').addClass('error').fadeTo(900,1);  
                    });    
                }  
            });  
            return false;   
            });  
            $("#password").blur(function(){  
            $("#login_form").trigger('submit');  
        });  
    });  
    </script>
```

But I'm trying to change this to be conform to CodeIgniter.

**v_login.php view**

```
           <script type="application/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#submit').click(function(e) {
        var form_data = {
          username : $('.username').val(),
          password : $('.password').val() };
        e.preventDefault();
        var loader = $('<img/>', {
          'src':'assets/img/ajax-loader.gif',
          'id':'ajax-loader'
        }); 
        //loader.insertAfter($('#cancel'));




      $.ajax({ //
        url: "<?php echo site_url('login/ajax_check'); ?>",
        type: 'POST',
        async : false,
        data: form_data,
        success: function(msg) {

          $('#message').html(msg);
          if(form_data == 'unknown user'){
              $("#message").fadeTo(2000,1,function(){        
                $(this).html('<img src="assets/img/icon_error.gif"> Username or password error.').addClass('error').fadeTo(900,1);  
                });
          }


        }
      });
        return false;
      });
    });
  </script>
```

**c_login.php controller**

```
   function ajax_check() {
            //if($this->input->post('ajax') == '1') {
            if($this->input->is_ajax_request()){
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'username', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'password', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
                $this->form_validation->set_message('required', 'Please fill in the fields');
                    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
                        echo validation_errors();
                    } else {
                        $this->load->model('m_access');
                        $user = $this->m_access->check_user($this->input->post('username'),$this->input->post('password'));
                    if($user) {
                        echo 'login successful';
                        //$this->load->view('welcome');
                    } else {
                        echo 'unknown user'; //
                        //echo ' <img src="assets/img/icon_error.gif"> Username or password not valid';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

But the problem is it's not showing the working as I want it to be. Any ideas? I'd really love to finish this problem and I'm new to Ajax and CI so I beg your pardon. Help will be truly appreciated by me. Thanks.

Comment: "But the problem is it's not showing the working as I want it to be". I'm sorry but that doesn't tell me anything about the problem you're having. Please be more specific.

Comment: @a.real.human.being the problem is, it's just showing the loader.gif, but I can't make it to last for 5 seconds

Comment: meaning, it flashes past, or it hangs forever, or it last 10 seconds but not 5...or, can you give us a specific technical definition of your problem?

Comment: @jmadsen it shows indefinitely, i want the loader.gif just to last for 5 seconds

Comment: So I will bet you all the money you have in your pocket that there is an error being thrown on the CI side, causing the javascript not to complete. Use Firebug or Chrome tools and look at your ajax request

Comment: sorry, I don't have time to do much more at the moment, but this blog post is about helping people learn to debug ajax issues, and may be useful:  http://codebyjeff.com/blog/2013/04/how-do-i-use-ajax-with-framework-x

Comment: @jmadsen actually, I don't know how to put the timer for the loader.gif, and if you can help me with that.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40862/discussion-between-dunkey-and-jmadsen)